# I'm struggling with scanf with float

Tags: c

I am having some issues with the `scanf` function.

I am trying to `printf` a `scanf` result, but it only returns **0.00000**

Can someone help me? Here is my code done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  float grade;  
  char choise; 

  do {
    printf ("Type your grade: ");
    scanf("%f", &grade);
    printf("Want to continue? s/n: ");
    scanf(" %c", &choise);
    printf("%s \n", &choise);
    printf("%f", &grade);
    
    }while(choise != 'n');
}
```

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: You have **two** `printf` calls that are very wrong and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You need the `&` with `scanf` (most of the time), but you do *not* need them with `printf`.  This can be confusing at first.

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%f", &grade);` is wrong

try

```
 printf("%f", grade);
```

But there are many other issues.  At the very least, you must check the values returned by `scanf`, and you should use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        float grade;
        char choise;

        do {
                printf("Type your grade: ");
                fflush(stdout);
                if( scanf("%f", &grade) != 1 ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        exit(1);
                }
                printf("Want to continue? s/n: ");
                fflush(stdout);
                if( scanf(" %c", &choise) != 1 ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        exit(1);
                }
                printf("%c\n", choise);
                printf("%f\n", grade);
        } while( choise != 'n' );
        return 0;
}
```

If you don't check the value returned by `scanf`, you don't know if any data was written into the variable.  Since neither `choise` nor `grade` is initialized, attempting to read those values if `scanf` did not assign to them is undefined behavior.  The behavior is also undefined if the input stream contains a value that cannot be represented as a float (eg, if it is a value greater than FLT_MAX), but that's really just an argument for avoiding `scanf` rather than a suggestion to try to make `scanf` usable.  You *can* try to use `scanf` to make a user friendly interface, but it's really not worth the effort.  Much better to simply abort on bad input.  (If you want a user friendly interface, I would recommend you are using the wrong language.)  See http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html for more details on why you really ought to just avoid `scanf` completely.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not notice that. So simple...

Comment: @SarThori you can mark the question solved by clicking on the tick on the left under the up votes : )

Answer (score 2):

These calls of `printf`

```
printf("%s \n", &choise);
printf("%f", &grade);
```

are incorrect.

In the first call you are trying to output a single character as a string. In the second call you are trying to output a pointer of the type `float *` as an object of the type `float`.

Instead you have to write

```
printf("%c\n", choise);
printf("%f\n", grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
printf("%s \n", &choise);
printf("%f", &grade);
```

are wrong.

They should be

```
printf("%c \n", choise);
printf("%f", grade);
```

The `%s` format specifier should only be used for strings (null-terminated sequences of characters), not individual characters. The expression `&choice` does not point to a string, as the character sequence is not null-terminated.

Also, the `%c` and `%f` format specifiers require values, not addresses, when using them with `printf`. Only when using them with `scanf` should you pass an address.